# Toolbar not appearing within Selenium IDE for Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, firefox-addon, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Selenium IDE 3.0.3.0 along with Firefox Quantum 60.0.2. When I use the Selenium IDE, the toolbar does not appear, so I cannot access most of the functionality described online about Selenium.

[image: Picture of my Selenium IDE]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the toolbar, you will need to either find alternative to Selenium IDE (I'd recommend Kantu or Sideex) or go back to an earlier version of Firefox (no later than version 54 - https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/54.0b9/) and download the legacy Selenium IDE. I wouldn't recommend this, however, as older versions of software can pose a security risk to your computer.